# Order 1st ng-repeat by the 2nd ng-repeat value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Lets say I have two ng-repeats like

```
<div ng-repeat="category in categories">
    {{category.name}}
    <div ng-repeat="subcategory in category.subcategories">
       {{subcategory.value}}
    </div>
</div>
```

and I've would like to order the categories according to the subcategory.value?

JS:

```
$scope.categories = [
    {
      name: "1st category",
      subcategories: [
        {
          name: "1st subcategory",
          value: 1
        },
        {
          name: "2nd subcategory",
          value: 2
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "2nd category",
      subcategories: [
        {
          name: "3rd subcategory",
          value: 5
        },
        {
          name: "4th subcategory",
          value: 6
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "3rd category",
      subcategories: [
        {
          name: "4th subcategory",
          value: 3
        },
        {
          name: "5th subcategory",
          value: 4
        }
      ]
    }
```

];

Also made a Plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/8ugJckYRrZoyQlnBYkuU

Expected result should be:

```
2nd category
6
5
3rd category
4
3
1st category
2
1
```

Comment: can you explain a little more or give you expected result?

Comment: Added expected result to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by creating a customOrderBy.

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="category in categories | customOrderBy:'subcategories':'value':true">
```

JS:

```
.filter('customOrderBy', function() {
  return function(items, field, value, reverse) {
    var filtered = [];
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
      item.subcategories.sort(function(a, b){
        return a[value]-b[value];
      });
      if(reverse) item.subcategories.reverse();
      filtered.push(item);
    });
    filtered.sort(function (a, b) {
      return (a[field][0][value] > b[field][0][value] ? 1 : -1);
    });
    if(reverse) filtered.reverse();
    return filtered;
  };
});
```

Here's the Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/8ugJckYRrZoyQlnBYkuU?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Below this code:

```
<div ng-repeat="category in categories | orderBy:'name':true">
    {{category.name}}
    <div ng-repeat="subcategory in category.subcategories | orderBy: 'value':true">
       {{subcategory.value}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Needs to be something like ` |  orderBy:"subcategories.value"` in the category

Comment: Do you want to order reverse?

Comment: Yes so the category with biggest subcategory.value is on the top. In this case it being the 2nd category

Answer (score 0):

For your expected result:

```
<div ng-repeat="category in categories | orderBy: '-name'">
   {{category.name}}
   <div ng-repeat="subcategory in category.subcategories | orderBy: '-value'">
       {{subcategory.value}}
   </div>
</div>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/t3UVFpb3TLGAQdYMIbbd?p=preview

Comment: Didnt mean this. If the values of the 1st Category are bigger then it doesnt work as expected.

Comment: This simple orderby will not work for you situation, write some logic in you controller and create a list of according to your need and simply bind it.